# How to animate a bar plot in R that represents one variable increasing over time, synchronised with a second animation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, gif, gganimate

I would like to create an animated bar plot that increases at specified times, synchronized with another plot (links to both gifs at bottom). Whenever the ball hits the right side wall I'd like it to display as a synchronized increase in the bar graph.

The data (bar_data) is filtered from a data set of 17000 time steps. There is only 4 occasions where the ball hits the wall, so 4 occasions where the impulse should increase on the bar graph.

The data:

```
impulse <- c(8e-24, 8e-24, 8e-24, 8e-24)
cume_impulse <- c(8.0e-24, 1.6e-24, 2.4e-24, 3.2e-24) #cumulative total
time_steps <- c(1.132, 6.136, 11.140, 16.144) #time step at which the increase occurs
bar_data <- data.frame(time_steps, impulse, cume_impulse)
```

summary of my task:

- create an animation which shows a growing bar plot, synchronized with right side wall contact. Two gifs side-by-side should form a single animation.

I've managed to get the animations paired into the same gif, but I can't get the timing right.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(dplyr)
library(gifski)
library(tidyverse)
library(magick)

plots <- bar_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x_pos, y = cume_impulse)) + geom_col()

#label the animation for the bar plot as bar_anim
bar_anim <- plots + transition_time(time_steps)

#set the parameters and display the bar plot animation
bar_gif <- animate(bar_anim, height = 500, width = 800, fps = 20, duration = 20)

#save the bar plot to a gif file
anim_save("bar_impulse.gif", bar_gif)

#the following two lines are required before the image_append function will process
mgif_particle <- image_read(particle_gif) 
mgif_bar <- image_read(bar_gif)

#join the first fraomes of the gifs
paired_gif <- image_append(c(mgif_particle[1], mgif_bar[1]))

for(i in 2:317){
  combined <- image_append(c(mgif_particle[i], mgif_bar[i]))
  paired_gif <- c(paired_gif, combined)
}

anim_save("bar_plus_particle.gif", paired_gif)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Gif links:
[bar gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS1XJ.gif)
[ball motion gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/134C6.gif)

additional details. This code precedes the code above:

```
m <- 1e-26    #Mass of a particle in kg
vx_i <- 400   #initial x velocity in m/s
vy_i <- 200   #initial y velocity in m/s

#creating variables for the initial coordinates of the particle
x_i <- round(runif(n = 1, min = 0,max = 1), 3)
y_i <- round(runif(n = 1, min = 0,max = 1), 3)

#initialise vectors that will be added to a data frame
x_pos <- round(seq(x_i, (x_i + 17), 0.001), 3) #17 was an arbitrary choice to allow for a few bounces on the right wall
y_pos <- round(seq(y_i, (y_i + 17), 0.001), 3) 
time_steps <- seq(0, 17.001, 0.001)

#loop to detect x direction wall contact
xv = 0.0004
for (i in 1 + seq_along(x_pos)) {
  if (x_pos[i-1] > 1 | x_pos[i-1] < 0 ){xv = xv*(-1)}
  x_pos[[i]] <- round(x_pos[[i-1]] + xv, 4)
  }

#loop for y direction wall contact
yv = 0.0002
for (i in 1 + seq_along(y_pos)) {
  if (y_pos[i-1] > 1 | y_pos[i-1] < 0 ){yv = yv*(-1)}
  y_pos[[i]] <- round(y_pos[[i-1]] + yv, 4)
  }

#creating a data frame with the particle's kinematic information (this line must come after the loops)
pos_data <- data.frame(x_pos, y_pos, time_steps)

graph1 = pos_data %>% ggplot(aes(x_pos, y_pos)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "red", size = 2) + 
  xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) + xlim(0, 1) + ylim(0, 1)

#initialising vector for x-momentum. Same length as x_pos with arbitrary values.
px <- rep(xv,length(x_pos)) 

#add a vector to pos_data called x_dif to pos_data that represents the change in x position between successive time steps
pos_data$x_dif <- c(0, diff(pos_data$x_pos))

# add a vector to pos_data called x_turn which will help detect changes in direction
pos_data$x_turn <- c(0, diff(sign(pos_data$x_dif)))

# add a cumulative total column for impulse on right wall called cume_impulse
pos_data$cume_impulse <- cumsum(pos_data$impulse)

#add a vector to pos_data which will include the impulse magnitude on the right wall at each time step
pos_data <- pos_data %>% mutate(impulse = case_when(abs(pos_data$x_turn) == 2 ~ 2*(vx_i*m),
                           abs(pos_data$x_turn) != 2 ~ 0))

graph1_animation = graph1 + transition_time(time_steps) +
  labs(subtitle = "{frame_time}") + ease_aes('linear') +
  shadow_wake(wake_length = 0.05) #animation code

particle_gif <- animate(graph1_animation, height = 500, width = 800, nframes = 317)

anim_save("particle_bounce.gif", particle_gif) #saves animation as a gif file

#Filter the data to only include frames that include impulse, and x_pos = 1 (right wall)
bar_data <- filter(pos_data,impulse!=0 & x_pos == 1)

#new column in bar_data called "cume_impulse" - cumulative total of the impulse on the right wall
bar_data["cume_impulse"] <- cumsum(bar_data$impulse)
```

Most recent adjustments:

```
## initial position for particle
x_i <- round(runif(n = 1, min = 0,max = 1), 3)
y_i <- round(runif(n = 1, min = 0,max = 1), 3)

## more initial conditions
m <- 1e-26    #Mass of a particle in kg
vx_i <- 400   #initial x velocity in m/s
vy_i <- 200   #initial y velocity in m/s

#initialise vectors that will be added to a data frame
x_pos <- round(seq(x_i, (x_i + 17), 0.001), 3)
y_pos <- round(seq(y_i, (y_i + 17), 0.001), 3) 
time_steps <- seq(0, 17.001, 0.001)
#xv_column <- seq(0, 17.001, 0.001) # don't think this is necessary

#loop for x direction wall contact
xv = 0.0004
for (i in 1 + seq_along(x_pos)) {
  if (x_pos[i-1] > 1 | x_pos[i-1] < 0 ){xv = xv*(-1)}
  x_pos[[i]] <- round(x_pos[[i-1]] + xv, 4)
}

#loop for y direction wall contact
yv = 0.0002
for (i in 1 + seq_along(y_pos)) {
  if (y_pos[i-1] > 1 | y_pos[i-1] < 0 ){yv = yv*(-1)}
  y_pos[[i]] <- round(y_pos[[i-1]] + yv, 4)
}

#creating a data frame with the particle's kinematic information (this line must come after the loops)
pos_data <- data.frame(x_pos, y_pos, time_steps)

#initialising vector for x-momentum. Same length as x_pos with arbitrary values.
px <- rep(xv,length(x_pos)) 

#add a vector to pos_data called x_dif to pos_data that represents the change in x position between successive time steps
pos_data$x_dif <- c(0, diff(pos_data$x_pos))

# add a vector to pos_data called x_turn which will help detect changes in direction
pos_data$x_turn <- c(0, diff(sign(pos_data$x_dif)))

#add a vector to pos_data which will include the impulse magnitude on the right wall at each time step
pos_data <- pos_data %>% mutate(impulse = case_when(abs(pos_data$x_turn) == 2 ~ 2*(vx_i*m),
                                                    abs(pos_data$x_turn) != 2 ~ 0))

# add a cumulative total column for impulse on right wall called cume_impulse
pos_data$cume_impulse <- cumsum(pos_data$impulse)







## ------------------------------------ tjebo's ------------------------------------------------------


## --- I may have misunderstood which data you used.Did you use the the length 4 vectors below for the bar_data frame? 
## ---- I presumed not, so I made the bar_data frame similar length to pos_data.

## using your pos_data frame and impulse vector

## I have changed the order of cume_impulse, because it somehow made more sense
#cume_impulse <- c(1.6e-24, 2.4e-24, 3.2e-24, 8.0e-24)
## time steps need to be character, for the later merge
#time_steps <- as.character(c(1.132, 6.136, 11.140, 16.144))
bar_data <- data.frame(pos_data$time_steps, pos_data$impulse, pos_data$cume_impulse)

df1 <- pos_data %>% mutate(time_steps = as.character(time_steps))

# --- data frames wouldn't merge because of the automatic name change to the columns. This was how I fixed that. Unsure why this didn't effect you
names(bar_data)[names(bar_data)=="pos_data.time_steps"] <- "time_steps"     
names(bar_data)[names(bar_data)=="pos_data.cume_impulse"] <- "cume_impulse"
names(bar_data)[names(bar_data)=="pos_data.impulse"] <- "impulse"

# --- I fragmented the code to help me understand the individual commands, and also to locate where it was breaking down
df2 <- pos_data %>% left_join(bar_data, by = "time_steps")
df3 <- pos_data %>% bind_rows(., .)
df4 <- df3 %>% mutate(
  time_steps = as.numeric(time_steps), 
  panel = rep(c("bar", "dot"), each = nrow(pos_data)), 
  ## removing x and y for the bar panel
  across(c(x_pos, y_pos), ~ifelse(panel == "bar", NA, .x))
)

## --- I wasn't quite sure what this command was for
df5 <- df4 %>% fill(cume_impulse)

## --- I presumed this converted the NA's into zeros in cume_impulse?
df5$cume_impulse[is.na(df5$cume_impulse)] <- 0
## --- Looks like this converts the cume_impulse values that correspond to dot as NA. Unsure why it's necessary though.
df5$cume_impulse[df5$panel == "dot"] <- NA

set.seed(1)
times <- sort(sample(unique(df5$time_steps), 100))
df_frac <- df5[df5$time_steps %in% times, ]

## dummy data for facet range
bar_range <- data.frame(x= .5, cume_impulse = range(df5$cume_impulse, na.rm = T), panel = "bar")
## separate out the aesthetics to the respective layers
p <-
  ggplot(df_frac) +
  geom_blank(data = bar_range, aes(x = .5, y = cume_impulse)) +
  ## need position = "identity"
  geom_col(aes(x = .5, y = cume_impulse), na.rm = T, position = "identity") +
  geom_point(aes(x_pos, y_pos), na.rm = T) +
  facet_wrap(~panel, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))

p_anim <- p + transition_time(time_steps)

# this is not random = there are 100 unique time steps, and now 100 frames 
animate(p_anim, fps = 20, duration = 5)
```

Comment: almost reproducible - what is xpos (I guess just "1"), but more importantly, what is `particle_gif`

Comment: That's correct, xpos is just 1 whenever the ball is in contact with the right side wall. But more generally it's the position of the ball in the x direction, from 0-1. I was trying to be concise by not adding all the previous code, but would you like me to add the section relating to particle_gif?

Comment: it would indeed be helpful to have at least the data frame for the dots - so to make those coordinates more like in your example

Comment: I've added the rest of the code to the bottom of the question. Hopefully that helps. Thanks again @tjebo.

Comment: to your comments in the code: I have used the bar data frame with four rows - and that's probably where things went amiss. The fill command was to replace trailing NAs with the same value, so that the same value (bar height) will be displayed at each time point till the next increase. The 0 step was indeed replacing the first NA till the first "visible" bar - just to get rid of the NAs

Comment: @tjebo my latest attempts to run the code are breaking down at the fill function during the creation of the df data frame. I think it's because after joining the two data frames, it creates two columns (cume_impulse.x & cume_impulse.y). I'm curious as to why you didn't run into this problem.

Comment: I am not using the same pos_data as you. Do not do those steps after `pos_data <- data.frame(x_pos, y_pos, time_steps)`. Or, if you need this to define the cumulative sum steps, do this separately elsewhere.

Comment: Amazing! That worked. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. And thanks for the coffee :) This is very kind of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your life (and your code :) a bit easier by creating those two plots as one single plot - using facets. This requires just a bit of data hacking, so that you create two separate panels.

The biggest challenge is actually to generate two different "ease_aes" for geom_bar and geom_point. As both geom layers are using the same aesthetic (x and y), we cannot simply define `ease_aes` for one of those aesthetics. I don't think one *can* define two different `ease_aes` for different geoms without a little hack. You have already quite a lot of intermediate time steps - I am merging this data with the bar code data and the removing the x/y according to the facet panel. The merge only properly works when your time values are character, probably because of floating point issues. Because my computer is not great and it is extremely computationally intense to compute 17000 frames, I will reduce the data drastically.

The only issue that I see which is still left, is that gganimate seems to switch the aesthetic "between" frames - thus the bar increases with a small delay when compared with the dot touching the wall. I guess this can be tolerable. Maybe there are ways to change this by using different transition objects. I don't know.

```r
suppressMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(gganimate)
})

## using your pos_data frame and impulse vector

## I have changed the order of cume_impulse, because it somehow made more sense
cume_impulse <- c(1.6e-24, 2.4e-24, 3.2e-24, 8.0e-24)
## time steps need to be character, for the later merge
time_steps <- as.character(c(1.132, 6.136, 11.140, 16.144))
bar_data <- data.frame(time_steps, impulse, cume_impulse)

df <-
  pos_data %>%
  ## you need time steps as character for a correct merging - probably a floating point issue
  mutate(time_steps = as.character(time_steps)) %>%
  left_join(bar_data, by = "time_steps")  %>%
  bind_rows(., .) %>%
  ## adding a facetting variable
  mutate(
    time_steps = as.numeric(time_steps), 
    panel = rep(c("bar", "dot"), each = nrow(pos_data)), 
  ## removing x and y for the bar panel
    across(c(x_pos, y_pos), ~ifelse(panel == "bar", NA, .x))
  ) %>%
## giving values to all time steps
  fill(cume_impulse) 
df$cume_impulse[is.na(df$cume_impulse)] <- 0
## removing y for dot panel 
df$cume_impulse[df$panel == "dot"] <- NA

## I am reducing the data to a mere fraction, because you get the same plot with way
## less computation (also, otherwise my computer is crashing). 
## I do this after merging etc so not to accidentally remove the bar values
## I'm deliberately selecting 100 unique time steps for the animation (so that frame number is equivalent to time stamps)
set.seed(1)
times <- sort(sample(unique(df$time_steps), 100))
df_frac <- df[df$time_steps %in% times, ]

## dummy data for facet range
bar_range <- data.frame(x= .5, cume_impulse = range(df$cume_impulse, na.rm = T), panel = "bar")
## separate out the aesthetics to the respective layers
p <-
  ggplot(df_frac) +
  geom_blank(data = bar_range, aes(x = .5, y = cume_impulse)) +
  ## need position = "identity"
  geom_col(aes(x = .5, y = cume_impulse), na.rm = T, position = "identity") +
  geom_point(aes(x_pos, y_pos), na.rm = T) +
  facet_wrap(~panel, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))

p_anim <- p + transition_time(time_steps)

## this is not random = there are 100 unique time steps, and now 100 frames 
animate(p_anim, fps = 20, duration = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi tjebo, thank you very much for the response. I appreciate all the effort you put in, and it's very helpful. I'll adopt the idea of using facets.

One thing that I may not have made clear is that I would like the bar plot to make discrete jumps every time the ball contacts the wall on the right. Do you think that would be possible?

Comment: yes, this is possible, at least I can see a way to do this - It would require a bit of hacking, in my opinion. If you provide the coordinates for the points, then I can show my idea better.

Comment: @Zinn I've added one possibility. It may look daunting, but it's not very complicated

Comment: @Zinn turns out with your data it's a bit of different challenges - I have updated this now. Please go through comments etc, there are some important caveats

Comment: Thanks @tjebo. What you prodecued looks great. ALthough I couldn't quote replicate it unfortunately. I will paste the code that I adapted from your example which displays an animation similar to yours, but not quite. Hopefully it will be clear to you where I've gone wrong.

Comment: I just added my latest attempt with your code under at the bottom of the question. Thanks tjebo!